# How can I import .pyd module in IronPython?

Tags: python, ironpython, osc, python.net, pyd

I have seen some Q&A about this problem. In most cases, it shows [CPython Extensions for IronPython](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/cpython_extensions.shtml).

But it is too old to download module files. The download link doesn't work, so I can't resolve the problem.

What should I do for using .pyd in IronPython. Is it impossible?

[Updata]
I want use the OSC communication in IronPython. 
However the library module of OSC that I use([pyOSC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOSC)) is for Python, not for IronPython.
I found that pyOSC needed socket.pyd.
This is why I would like to know a way to import .pyd into IronPython. 
Or, if there is another way to use OSC communication in IronPython (without using pyOSC), I would like to know it.

Comment: @Jeroen not sure why you closed - this question looks clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

IronClad, the CPython extensions for IronPython, is now dead and does not support the last version of IronPython (2.7). Furthermore, IronPython itself is now essentially dead.

I would consider using [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) which allows for interop between .Net and Python (and is still maintained). It allows you to call Python (CPython) from .Net programs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Can you tell me how should I do concretely?
Sorry, I don't have enough information and skill...

Comment: @Morimi see this tutorial how to use .pyd extensions (in this case numpy) from pythonnet:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/README.md